# Orden de inserción de los elementos en un diccionario

Tags: python

Es posible conocer el orden en el que los elementos de un diccionario fueron insertados, es decir:

```
d = {}
d['a'] = 'A'
d['b'] = 'B'
d['c'] = 'C'
d['d'] = 'D'
d['e'] = 'E'
for key, value in d.items():
    print key, value
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
b B
e E
a A
c C
d D
```

Al iterar sobre los elementos del diccionario se imprimen los valores de forma arbitraria. ¿Existe alguna forma de "recordar" el orden de inserción?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Puedes usar para eso un `OrderedDict` que es como su nombre lo indica un diccionario ordenado.

Esto te permite insertar elementos y que luego sean obtenidos en el mismo orden de inserción por un iterador. Por ejemplo:

```
import collections

d = collections.OrderedDict()
d['a'] = 'A'
d['b'] = 'B'
d['c'] = 'C'
d['d'] = 'D'
d['e'] = 'E'

for k, v in d.items():
    print k, v
```

Esto imprime lo siguiente:

```
a A
b B
c C
d D
e E
```

Cabe resaltar que, en el caso de `OrderedDict`, al comparar si dos diccionarios son iguales también importará el orden por lo que los siguientes dos diccionarios no son considerados iguales

```
d1 = collections.OrderedDict()
d1['a'] = 'A'
d1['b'] = 'B'

d2 = collection.OrderedDict()
d2['b'] = 'B'
d2['a'] = 'A'

print d1 == d2 #Falso
```

Comment: ¡Excelente! Incluso compara el orden. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 8):

Los diccionarios no son ordenados de por sí (su orden es determinístico, pero depende de distintos factores como el "hash" de sus índices, el orden de inserción, etc).

- Si usas Python 2.7 o superior puedes usar [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) tal y como comenta Carlos en su respuesta.
- Si usas un Python anterior a 2.6 puedes usar el paquete `ordereddict`. Simplemente instálalo con:

  ```
  pip install ordereddict
  ```
- Para versiones aún más antiguas puedes consultar esta respuesta en [OrderedDict for older versions of python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1617087/1983854).

Comment: Gracias! La solución es usar el `OrderedDict` como mencionas

Answer (score 2):

Segun esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60848/how-do-you-retrieve-items-from-a-dictionary-in-the-order-that-theyre-inserted ¡NO ES POSIBLE!

La solución sería implementar ANTES de la inserción una metodología de orden según se vayan insertando las llaves y el valor de la llave o llaves en cuestión.
En el link antes mencionado está muy bien explicado y posee algunos links que amplían este tema.

Comment: Si, la respuesta correcta es no, no es posible usando los diccionarios originales. Pero tambien preguntaba si habia alguna forma y la mas sencilla hasta el momento es la mencionada por Carlos. Gracias!

Comment: @CésarBustíos en el link mencionado tienes ejemplos sobre el tema en cuestion, miralo ! , posiblemente no sea la mas facil, pero da una idea de implementacion Suerte !

Comment: En la [respuesta aceptada](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60862/186133) de ese link que por cierto data del 2008 y editada en 2011 indica que ya fue implementada con `orderedDict` en python 2.7 y 3.1.